# Sending udp message to a fixed ip address on lan in C

Tags: c++, udp

I am writting a module that can send message from a device (client) to a VM runnning ubuntu (server) in the same subnet (192.168.50.x)

This is my client code

```
// Client side implementation of UDP client-server model
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>
  
#define PORT     37001
#define MAXLINE 1024
#define HOSTNAME "192.168.50.10"
  
// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    std::string intro = "Hello from client";
    char *hello = const_cast<char* > (intro.c_str());
    struct sockaddr_in     servaddr;
  
    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
      
    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOSTNAME);
      
    int n;
    socklen_t len;
      
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello),
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
            sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");
          
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, 
                MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);
  
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my server code

```
// Server side implementation of UDP client-server model
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>
  
#define PORT     37001
#define MAXLINE 1024
#define HOSTNAME  "192.168.50.10"
  
// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    std::string intro = "Hello from server";
    char *hello = const_cast<char*> (intro.c_str());
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
      
    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
      
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
      
    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(HOSTNAME);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the socket with the server address
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, 
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\nservaddr.sin_family: %ld  \n", servaddr.sin_family);
    printf("servaddr.sin_port: %d \n", servaddr.sin_port);;
    printf("servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr: %ld \n" , servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
      
    socklen_t len;
    int n;
  
    len = sizeof(cliaddr);  //len is value/resuslt
  
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, 
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
                &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Client : %s\n", buffer);
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), 
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
            len);
    printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 
      
    return 0;
}
```

On running it seem to get stuck. Messages that was supposed to be send does not appear to other end. I tried running ping to find out what is the error . Ping seem to work from both end

1. Is the IP Address and PORT  u are trying ti bind in the server side code, the ip address of the PC hosting the Server?
2. The IP Address u are setting for the client end would be where you are going to send to ie the Server IP address and port number?

REgards

Comment: Please use your favorite web search engine and look for some tutorial for network beginners. It will answer a lot of your questions and help you with your code.

Comment: Learn to troubleshoot network issues. Use `tcpdump` to check whether the traffic is actually sent and received correctly. Verify firewall configuration. I'm not going to review code if I'm unsure about your network configuration. It's also C++ code and not C.

Comment: Your code never checks the return value of `sendto()`, so it doesn't know whether the UDP packets was actually sent or not.  For all you know, `sendto()` might be returning -1 and setting `errno` to the appropriate error value.

Comment: Also make sure that your machines don't have firewalls active, as firewalls will typically block incoming UDP packets.